# How to start gnome's built in screen recorder via command line?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-3, screencast

How to start gnome's built in screen recorder via command line?

I have gone through  [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/359587/739431)

the command I am using is

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Screencast --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screencast --method org.gnome.Shell.Screencast.Screencast "test_ %d_ %t.webm" "{}"
```

So it is happening as if screenshot was taken. I mean Screencast is not starting rather it is generating the file with 1sec in this format "test_ %d_ %t.webm"

How can I start recording and stop it with Ctrl+C in the terminal?

Comment: This question is better suited for __AskUbuntu__. Consider moving it there. See similar question: [start gnome screen recorder command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190696/start-gnome-screen-recorder-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for this answer for years. Finally stumbled upon following shell-script by *Tor Hedin Brønner* (hedning)

Gist: [Start gnome shell screen cast from command line](https://gist.github.com/hedning/008462f98da4b8cf584e1f1e94de06f3)

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i python3 -p python3.pkgs.dbus-python

import dbus
import time
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.gnome.Shell", "/org/gnome/Shell/Screencast")

obj.Screencast("Auto %d %t.webm", [],
               dbus_interface="org.gnome.Shell.Screencast")
time.sleep(999999)
```

️ It uses the [nix-shell](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/developing-with-nix-shell.html) and [`dbus-python`](https://pypi.org/project/dbus-python/) (Python's D-Bus binding) to communicate with GNOME-shell over the [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) protocol.

✔️ Tested it and it works a treat.

Comment: Great answer. How can we replace the [nix-shell](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/developing-with-nix-shell.html) by any other common shell?

Comment: Nix shell is anything after `-i` as shell (or by default bash), but with dependency automatically installed @hc_dev. Replace it with python3 shebang and install the dependency yourself (dbus-python package).

Comment: Would someone happen to know how to change format and resolution?

Comment: you can post process it in VLC but the quality quickly degrades and becomes pretty unusable. better to just start with a screen grab, ffmpeg, and record at the resolution you desire.